# Xcode: Cant find rgb color picker for controls

Tags: xcode, color-picker, developer-tools

Using Xcode 4.3.2 I am unable to add color values by rgb.  The standard picker looks like this [image]

Which does not offer any input for rgb or have any sliders allowing me to set anything else.

The custom picker at this location http://www.panic.com/~wade/picker/ instructs me to install at

> /home/Library/ColorPickers.

However home is not editable.  So I placed it into

> /Users/username/Library/ColorPickers

which does nothing. (Is this correct?)  Can anyone explain how to properly install this?  Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I use this tool and it works fine, /home is referring to /Users/Username so you did place it in the right folder.

If the tool still isn't working then you will need to restart Xcode and possibly even the computer.

After that you simply open the standard picker in Xcode, it isn't replaced, a new tab is added to it.

[image]

Additionally, you can always manually specify RGB values in code, for example:

```
[myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:235.2/255 green:150.7/255 blue:35.1/255 alpha:1.0]];
```

The values are x/255 because UIColor expects a float value between 0 and 1 and this is an easy way to convert the standard RGB 255 values down to 0-1.

Comment: Thanks NSPostWhenIdle, however wouldn't you know it, it still does not work.  I tried restarting Xcode, even restarting the machine.  I do not know how to solve this problem and frankly don't have the time to fiddle any more with it.  I'll have to settle for programmatic techniques for now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it's simply that your Toolbar is not showing. Go to View->ShowTool bar and you should now see a tab bar of color picker options. For more information on installing custom color pickers, visit https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/AddingColorPickers.html